# Image stored in Laravel's storage folder does not appear in a React component

Tags: reactjs, laravel, storage

I successfully upload images to Laravel's storage folder (storage/images) with a React frontend.
I follow the Laravel docs in connection with File Storage and try to retrive the images: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#main-content

So I created a link in the filesystems.php:

```
public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
```

used the "php artisan storage:link" command,
and use asset to retrive the public link of an image:

```
$task["image"] = asset("images/".$task["image"]);
```

The image names are saved in a table and the images are saved with the same name in the storage/app/images folder.

In the response data the links of the images are right, but when my browser tries to reach them I got the "GET http://localhost:8000/images/12_1696229046.jpg 404 (Not Found)" error message.

So my question is that how can I show in a React frontend component the images that are stored in Laravel's storage/app/images folder?

Comment: Hello, in your public folder is there any existing images folder? before you do the php artisan storage:link

Comment: Well, I'm a bit confused aout it. I thought that the public/image folder is not neccessary if I use the store/app/images so I deleted the public/image. Now I tried to save another image and realized that the image is saved not only in the store/app/images folder but also in the public/image folder. Does this make sense? This way all the images will be duplicated and available for anyone on the web.